# MVC 3 Entity Model - adding methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What would be the best way to add methods to an Entity model.

Such-as, I have a `User` model and I would like to add a method to the class that would hash passwords.

I have tried making a `UserHelper` class that extends `User` but this seems almost counterproductive.

Comment: A bit more information would be handy.  is the user model a model in a models class, a data access layer where?

Comment: @griegs Sorry I wish I knew but see @Esteban Araya anwser, he seems to know what I'm talking about.

Comment: As well as partial classes, there's also [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). But I'd use partials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If EF classes are not already partial classes, you could modify the T4 template to make them partial classes.

A [partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a class that's defined across multiple files. At compile time, the compiler builds the class definition from all files. Partial classes are most commonly used to add code to classes that are generated through automated tools (and are normally destroyed each time the generation runs), such as the T4 template for EF.

With a partial class, as mentioned above, you could then add your methods on a separate file to the class you're trying to "extend".

Having said all of this, you may also consider [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Extension methods are a neat syntax/compiler trick to extend the functionality of types you can't (eg. you don't own the code or cant' subclass them) modify. By writing an extension method, you're basically writing a static method that will be called as if it was an instance method of the type you just extended.

I think either option is almost just as good, but I'd lean for the partial class method.

Comment: I'm glad that there is an elegant way to achievement this. Could you please explain further? This is my first .Net project and am a little lost.

Comment: @Paramout: I added a bit more info; hope that helps.

Comment: Ah thank you. It's seems as though I have to use the full namespace when calling the new methods even though I have the class imported(using). Is this correct?

Comment: @Paramount: No, that should not be the case. Make sure you don't have a class with the same name in a different namespace already defined.

Comment: There is not, other than the partial class.

Answer (score 3):

Although partial classes and extension methods definitely can serve your purpose here, I think in this specific case you're better off handing over responsibility for password hashing to an authentication service of some sort, rather than letting your model implement that logic. The service will then take for example a username and a password (in plain text, not yet hashed) as input, and return an `IPrincipal` on a successful authentication attempt, and something else otherwise (throw exception, return null, whatever you like to do to indicate that the authentication attempt failed).

Simplified, I'd call the service like so:

```
IPrincipal user = _authService.Authenticate(username, password);
if (user == null)
{
    ShowErrorMessage("No such user!");

}
else
{
    ShowStatusMessage("Login successful!");
}
```

This service will also handle creating new users, deleting users etc - perhaps contacting the database through a repository that uses EF. (Your EF model will in that case require a property to store the hashed password, but the hashing itself does not take place in the model - it is done by the service).